# EF Core Foreign Key configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, fluent, ef-core-2.0

Having an issue trying to set up a foreign key configuration.

> The relationship from 'OrderStatus.Order' to 'Order.OrderStatuses' with foreign key properties {'OrderId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int, 'TransactionId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
>   System.Exception; System.InvalidOperationException

The `Order.OrderId` and `OrderStatus.TransactionId` is what needs to join.

The model classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderStatus> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Context configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .ToTable("OrdersTable")
                .HasKey(o => new { o.OrderId, o.CustomerId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany(o => o.OrderStatuses)
                .WithOne(o => o.Order)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderStatus>()
                .ToTable("OrderStatusTable")
                .HasKey(os => os.TransactionId);
}
```

Comment: You are configuring a composite key for Order, do you really want multiple customers to be able to have the same order id?

Comment: I'm adapting my example. Assume that having multiple customers having the same order id is ok.

Comment: Then you will need to reference orders with the composite key you have configured.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: Try `.HasForeignKey(o => new { o.OrderId, o.CustomerId })`